# Как анимировать размер кнопки, если стандартный размер заранее не известен?

Tags: wpf, xaml

У меня есть шаблон для кнопок разных размеров. Хочу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку с этим шаблоном она уменьшалась на 1 пиксель со всех сторон, но как я сказал, размеры у всех кнопок разные, как это сделать через код xaml?

Comment: Анимировать отступы (`margin`)?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, помогло